# jQuery date picker to have date format as default value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this plugin for a date picker.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePicker.html

I need to have the default value of the text box be mm/dd/yyyy (kinda like value="mm/dd/yyyy").

So when I click on the field or calendar icon, the default value goes away and the date picker appears for me to pick the date.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would love to add this as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dateFormat and altField options of the date picker for this:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker

Answer (score 0):

If kelvinluck date-picker does not have a support for default value. You can set your date input form to the current date; if you are using PHP you can do this:

```
<input name="mydate" class=".date-pick" value="<?php echo date("m-d-Y"); ?>" />
```

I am sure the date picker will automatically recognize the default value you've set.

Comment: It supports a default value that is an actual date, but I can not set it to mm/dd/yyyy (the format with letters instead of numbers).

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDefaultToday.html

Comment: Please use date("m/d/Y") since that is the format of the datepicker you are using.

Comment: did you use this already? $('.date-picker').dpSetSelected('01/01/2010');

Comment: that works to set the default value to an actual date, but it does not let me enter a non-date value. For instance, this doesn't work:

'.dpSetSelected('mm/dd/yyyy')'

Comment: Do you really mean you wanted to set its default value as 'mm/dd/yyyy', the string particularly? i guess it has some sort of input filter. Did you try to set its default value in html?

Comment: Yes and yes, but it breaks the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is what someone gave to me and it worked. But I'm very sorry if it doesn't work for you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
</script>
```